# Automatic indexed sorted array maintained by Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, sorting

Is there a feature in java by which I define an array as to keep it in a sorted fashion which will let me insert or remove an element in this array. This is to avoid expensive re-sort when an element is to be added or removed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing Objects in your Array which are not duplicated and can be compared using a Comparable, you could use a TreeSet which will keep your elements in order at all times.

Comment: if i want to keep in order but with duplicates which datastructure??

Comment: You could use a TreeMultiSet with the [Multiset](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) Interface provided by Google